Conditions on SDE coefficients for well-posedness of Fokker-Planck equation
Consider the following $n$-dimensional Ito-SDE:
\begin{align}
dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)dt + \sigma(X_t,t)dW_t
\end{align}
What are the necessary regularity conditions on $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to ensure that the associated Fokker-Planck equation for the probability density $p(x,t)$ is well defined:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\mu_i\,p) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i x_j}\big((\sigma \sigma^T)_{ij}p\big)
\end{align}
Some references like Stochastic Processes and Applications state that $\mu$ and $\sigma$ must be "smooth", but it is not clear enough for me. It seems to me at least, that $\mu$ and $\sigma$ must be $C^1$ and $C^2$ in $x$ for the derivatives to make sense.
Could someone clarify this and confirm whether these regularity requirements are sufficient, or point me to a detailed reference?
